# Permission denied in inotify_add_watch using C programming

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

I am trying check "/dev/input/event3" file is available or not.

Have written code like below:

```
const char *device_path = "/dev/input/event3";

void check_Task (void)
{
static int kbdfd = -1;
int fd,length,wd;
struct input_event ie;
MSG_TYPE_T  msg;

 /*creating the INOTIFY instance*/
fd = inotify_init();

/*checking for error*/
if ( fd < 0 ) {
     perror( "inotify_init" );
     return ;
}

        wd = inotify_add_watch( fd, device_path, IN_CREATE | IN_DELETE );
        
 if(wd < 0){
        
        printf("could not add watch for %s, %s\n", device_path, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }   
    
    
while(1){
    length=read(fd, &ie, sizeof(struct input_event));
    if ((ie.type == 1) && (ie.value)){
                msg.msgID = MSG_IR_INPUT_FROM_NEXUS;
        msg.data[0]  = ie.code;
        OSA_SendUrgentMsg(gQidIrInput, &msg, sizeof(msg));
    }  
    }
            
}
```

Getting error like below

lin[   12.393190] type=1400 audit(1605548950.932:4): avc: denied { search } for pid=2804 comm="INPUT_T" name="input" dev="tmpfs" ino=7802 scontext=u:r:dtv_dvb:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:input_device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0

could not add watch for /dev/input/event3, Permission denied

Comment: From the man page: "the caller must have read permission for this file".  Do you?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am new to this, Could you please elaborate more .It will be very help full.

Comment: Look at the permissions on the file: `ls -l /dev/input/event3` and compare with the user and group who are running the program.  My system shows `crw-rw---- 1 root input` so your program would have to run as user `root` or a user who is in group `input`.

Comment: Is it SEpolicy issue. I founf SEpolicy issue in the log. is it true. I have updated in the question.

Comment: If the question is now how to modify the machine's SELinux policy to allow the access, then it is off-topic here, but it could be made into an on-topic question for [Super User SE](https://superuser.com/).  There probably are already relevant answers over there, too.